# Match formula (SQL'ish) against PHP array to return true or false

Tags: php, regex, match

This is a tricky one to explain. I have an associative array which I want to run a set of rules against to return true or false.

I was wondering if there is a library somewhere allowing me to compare a rule (or set of) against an array. Almost like SQL exept I have the record, I just need to see if the SQL would return it or not.

For Example:

```
$subject = array('name' => 'John Smith', 'age' => '44');
$formula = "name LIKE 'John%' AND (age = 44 OR age = 45)";
if(match($formula, $subject))
return true;
else 
return false;
```

The subject array is NOT from a database it is actually from a form post, otherwise I would just run the SQL and if it returned the correct record then it would be true. Plus this is something that I would like to use a lot with may different associative arrays so adding to a table then running the query to get the same record back will not be possible either. Basically I can't use a database.

Comment: The difficulty here would be parsing `$formula` - where does this string come from? Could you alter the format, or (ideally) use an array?

Comment: That was just an example. At the moment I use an array as follows: array('field'=>'name','operator'=>'==','value'=>'Jonh Smith') but it needs to be really complex.

Comment: Also I currently batch these together for matching more than one field or value. This is ok but I can't have nested rules like in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

You could maybe do something like this?

```
function match ($subject, $formula) {
  extract($subject);
  foreach ($formula as $rule) {
    if (!eval("return $rule;")) return FALSE;
  }
  return TRUE;
}

$formula = array(
  'substr($name,0,4) == "John"',
  '$age == 44 OR $age == 45'
);
$subject1 = array('name' => 'John Smith', 'age' => '44');
$subject2 = array('name' => 'Bob Jones', 'age' => '42');

var_dump(match($subject1, $formula)); // bool (TRUE)
var_dump(match($subject2, $formula)); // bool (FALSE)
```

This approach means your rules can be as complex as you like; for example, the above `$formula` can be compressed into this one rule:

```
$formula = array(
  'substr($name,0,4) == "John" AND ($age == 44 OR $age == 45)'
);
```

Because of the way it works, multiple rules effectively have an AND relationship - as soon as one rule fails, the function returns false.

You can write anything to like, using any PHP function you like, as long as it is a valid comparison expression.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an expression to be parsed as if it were SQL, then use an SQL parser....

```
$subject = array('name' => 'John Smith', 'age' => '44'); 
$formula = "'name' LIKE 'John%' AND ('age' = '44' OR 'age' = '45')";
$result=try_expression($subject, $formula);

function try_db_expression($subject, $formula) 
{
$keys=array_keys($subject);
$vals=array_values($subject);

foreach ($keys as $k=>$v) {
   $keys[$k]='/\b' . mysql_real_escape_string($v) . '\b/i';
}
foreach ($vals as $k=>$v) {
   $vals[$k]=mysql_real_escape_string($v);
}
$test=preg_replace($keys, $vals, $subject);
$res=mysql_query("SELECT ($test) AS evald");
if ($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) return $r['evald'];
return false;
}
```

> Basically I can't use a database

Then you'll have to build your own parser (not really - you can use PHP's eval - but you'll need to map the LIKE operator to PHP function).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few implementations like this. You are basically looking for "LINQ in PHP" and one that works against array data sets. [`PHPLinq`](http://phplinq.codeplex.com/)

- http://devzone.zend.com/1205/linq-for-php-language-integrated-query-for-php/
- http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/basic-linq-syntax-in-php-with-phplinq
- http://www.phpkode.com./scripts/item/plinq/
- There's also one on phpclasses, but I'm not linking there..

Most of them use a more ORM-like query method, not an SQL parser. (Which you could get from http://www.phpinsider.com/php/code/SafeSQL/ or http://pear.php.net/package/SQL_Parser)

You can mimic SQL expressions with a recursive regex. But you cannot as easily parse out and process them with preg_match or _replace_callback. I would not bother unless you really have only such simple examples.